# ipad detect when UIPopoverControllers are dismissed

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have several uiPopoverControllers in my universal iPad app. I now have a requirement to trigger a function once a certain popover has been dismissed. I can do this easily if the user clicks "close" inside the popover, but if they touch the screen to hide the popover, I cannot trigger my function.

I've been googling for some time and cannot seem to find any delegate methods which I might be able to use in my main view controller to capture them. I would love something like didDismissPopoverController - but my guess is it's not available.

IF not, I guess the only thing to do would be to detect the touches and trigger then? Basically I am highlighting a UITableView row and loading the popover. I need to deselect the row - so want to simply call [table reloaddata].

Thanks for any help on this one!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to assign a delegate to the `UIPopoverController` and then implement the `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` method. For example:

```
@interface FooController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    // ...
}
// ...
@end
```

When you instantiate the `UIPopoverController` (say, for this example, in `FooController`)...

```
UIPopoverController *popover = // ...
popover.delegate = self;
```

Then, you would implement the method:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // do something now that it's been dismissed
}
```

Granted, I haven't tested this but it seems like it should work...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover delegate method after the following assignment:
self.popoverController.delegate = self;

Note that popoverControllerDidDismissPopover delegate method does not get called if you programmatically call [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES].

Comment: This is true, look in the documentation: `The popover controller does not call this method in response to programmatic calls to the dismissPopoverAnimated: method. If you dismiss the popover programmatically, you should perform any cleanup actions immediately after calling the dismissPopoverAnimated: method.`